# How to drag and reposition image before upload to database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder how to drag and reposition image before uploading (Example would be uploading a cover to facebook page. You can upload a big image in a small container and drag it around to position which part is to be shown).

I hope for any advices on what could achieve what I want(I am familiar with only html,css, a bit of php and a bit of javascript), proper approach and etc, and if there is a special termin for this that I can research.

**UPDATE**
I used JqueryUI Draggable, but now it snaps from one part to the other of the image and doesn't save it like that in the db.

[image: how it snaps]

[image: how it snaps]

As of now I have this code in my `petitionimage.php`

```
<script>
 $( function() {
    $( "#output" ).draggable({ containment: "#draggable", scroll: true });
  } );
</script>

<form action="petitioncreation.php" enctype='multipart/form-data' runat="server" method="POST">
<div class="row" style="background-color:#203647;">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <h1 class="display-5 headerSize" style="color:#f7f7f7">За какво се бори петицията?</h1>
      <h5 class="header5Size" style="color:#f7f7f7">Въведете описание на петицията</h5>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-file">
        <input type='file' name='file' onchange="loadFile(event)" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>
        </div>
          <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="float:right; margin-top:5%;">
          Напред
          </button>
          <div id="draggable" class="output2">
            <img id="output" class="ui-widget-content"/>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of jQuery Draggable and found out about [Guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) which happened to be a very lightweight and easy to use plugin.